# Struggling to get VBA Shell to execute CMD

Tags: excel, vba, cmd

Hi Guys im trying to excute a cmd line from VBA but it keeps giveing me errors like "c:\program" is not reconised. ive been stuck here for hours adding Chr(34) and other things but still no luck.

here is my code

```
Path = """C:\Users\Phill\Desktop\Mortgage Illustration 211206142739.pdf"""
scommand = """C:\Program Files (x86)\A-PDF Data Extractor\PRCMD.exe""" & _
       Path

Shell "cmd.exe /k " & scommand, vbNormalFocus
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```vb
Dim exe, pth

exe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\A-PDF Data Extractor\PRCMD.exe"
pth = "C:\Users\Phill\Desktop\Mortgage Illustration 211206142739.pdf"

Shell "cmd.exe /k """"" & exe & """ """ & pth & """""", vbNormalFocus
```

EDIT: fixed - the whole command (exe plus path) also needs to be quoted...

Comment: Hi Tim thanks for the reply but when i exeicute your code i still get 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: My mistake - the whole command passed to /k needs to be quoted.