# Excel VBA Run Python script with blank spaces on file path

Tags: python, excel, vba

I've been trying to run a Python scrip from Excel VBA. The first attempt I did not have any problem it runs smoothly, then when I try on a pc where the file path  with blank spaces the scrips fails.
I already use triple quotes to avoid any problems but it seems not work.

Where is the script used

```
    Sub RunPythonScript()
Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExe As String
Dim PythonScript As String

Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

PythonExe = """C:\Program Files\...\python.exe"""
PythonScript = """C:\Work\Python\update_list.py""""

ObjShell.Run "cmd /k" & " " & PythonExe & " " & PythonScript

End Sub
```

Running this script gives me the following message:

'*C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*

Comment: try adding quotes around the part after /k. `objShell.Run "cmd /k """ & PythonExe & " " & PythonScript & """"`. and remove one quote from end of `update_list.py""""`

Comment: On a side note, is it possible to you to install anaconda and use xlwings instead? You may have more control there and play with retrievals within VBA

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70268058/struggling-to-get-vba-shell-to-execute-cmd/70268284#70268284

Comment: Perfect, the problem apparently were the quotes around the part after /k. Thank you so much