# Keep command prompt open after executing python script from excel macro

Tags: python-3.x, excel, vba

I am trying to execute a python script from excel macro. I want to keep the command prompt open to see the messages. Right now it gets closed very quickly after the script executes.
How can I keep the command prompt open even after the script is executed.

Comment: Can you rewrite your Python script so that it prints to a file rather than the command prompt? A standard way to keep a command prompt open for a Python script is to put something like `input()` at the bottom of the script, but depending on how you are invoking the script from VBA, that might block the VBA program.

Comment: Always helps to include your code when posting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73564937/478884