# Execute Python code that creates an image from Excel (VBA)

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have Python code that creates an image (jpg format). This code works in Jupyter and Visual Studio code.

I'm trying to execute the code from the Excel workbook that the code imports the data. The idea is to have a button in the Excel workbook to execute the Python code and obtain the image.

Code to execute the Python code in VBA:

```vb
Sub RunPythonScript_1()

Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExePath, PythonScriptPath As String

    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    
    PythonExePath = """C:\Users\227871\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe"""
    PythonScriptPath = """C:\Users\227871\OneDrive - Weir Group PLC\Francisca\Mejora App Weir\Balance\Balance Collahuasi\Balance 1.py"""
    
    objShell.Run PythonExePath & PythonScriptPath
    
End Sub
```

It doesn't show me errors. It appears in the console for one second and closes.

I expect that when I use the button in the Excel workbook, an image appears.

Comment: Check python with simple program `objShell.Run PythonExePath & " -c ""import os;print(os.getcwd());input()"""`

Comment: Maybe try https://stackoverflow.com/a/73564937/478884 and see if there's any error in your script.  Sometimes if the script assumes a certain active directory when run, it may error if called from VBA and the directory is not set to the expected value.