# Rscript opens but do not execute from VBA

Tags: r, vba, rscript

I run a Rscript from VBA, and currently my VBA code opens a shell of rscript.exe and the window do execute the script. It will run some code, but others it will close and send VBA message it has completed. Some of the code it does not like to run such as:

```
Excelticker <- (read_excel("ticker.xlsx",sheet="Tickers", range ="A1:A400"))
Excelticker <- Excelticker$Ticker
Excelticker <- na.omit(Excelticker)
    
financials <- getQuote(FirmsEG, what = yahooQF(c("P/E Ratio","Market Capitalization","Shares Outstanding","Currency","Earnings/Share")))
```

This is my VBA code

```
Public Sub Update()

Dim iEerrorcode As Integer
Dim MyRscript As String
Dim MyUpdate As String

MyRscript = "C:\Users\elowe\xxxx\M&A\models\test.R"

iEerrorcode = Run_R_Script(MyRscript)
MsgBox "Run"
End Sub
```

```
Function Run_R_Script(MyRscript As String, Optional RhomeDir As String = "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.2\bin\x64\Rscript.exe", Optional iStyle As Integer = 1, Optional bWaitTillComplete As Boolean = True) As Integer

Dim sPath As String
Dim shell As Object

'Define shell object
Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'Wrap the R path with double ""
sPath = """" & RhomeDir & """ """ & MyRscript & """"

'Run r using shell
Run_R_Script = shell.Run(sPath, iStyle, bWaitTillComplete)
End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to (eg) "ticker.xlsx" in your R script?  When you run the script from VBA the current directory may not be the same as when you run the script from R...

Comment: I tried your suggestion - It does not change any thing. But thanks for trying! :)

Comment: Try something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/70268284/478884 - maybe there's some useful information in the cmd window?